# Swap divs(Column Children) in Different Columns in Responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have `bootstrap column` arrangement as following and have few `div`s with different `height` inside the `columns`.

HERE IS THE [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRVLpP)

```css
.column>div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #ddd;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div#child-1 {
  height: 150px;
}

div#child-2 {
  height: 50px;
}

div#child-3 {
  height: 50px
}

div#child-4 {
  height: 100px;
}

div#child-5 {
  height: 100px;
}

div#child-6 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 column">
      <div id="child-1">1</div>
      <div id="child-3">3</div>
      <div id="child-5">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 column">
      <div id="child-2">2</div>
      <div id="child-4">4</div>
      <div id="child-6">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When it comes to mobile devices, I need to use `col-xs-12` for each columns.

Now I need to have the following structure formed in the responsive `#child-1`,  `#child-2`, `#child-3`, `#child-4`, `#child-5`, `#child-6`.

But for now I have the pattern mixed as `#child-1`,  `#child-3`, `#child-5`, `#child-2`, `#child-4`, `#child-6`.

How can I swap these elements to the alignment that I wanted?

Comment: it's time to upgrade to boostrap V4 where all this can be easier

Comment: @TemaniAfif Still I am not familiar with bootstrap 4 sir. Can you give me a working example sir

Comment: hmm, even V4 would be tricky ...

Comment: But when in V4 when I use `col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12` it won't perform like V3 does. That's why I avoid V4 @TemaniAfif

Comment: because the classes has changed and you should use `col-md-6 col-12`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Omg, I didn't aware of this. So how can I swap these `div`s in V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think float can be helpful for such layout then on small device you can switch to flexbox (or even CSS-grid) and adjust the order. The main trick is to have all the elements inside one container so that you can easily handle them:

```css
.container {
  max-width:1124px;
  margin:auto;
}
.column>div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #ddd;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:calc(50% - 10px);
}

div#child-1 {
  height: 150px;
  float:left;
}

div#child-2 {
  height: 50px;
  float:right;
}

div#child-3 {
  height: 50px;
  float:left;
}

div#child-4 {
  height: 100px;
  float:right;
}

div#child-5 {
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}

div#child-6 {
  height: 150px;
  float:right;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  .column > div {
      width:auto;
  }
  #child-1 {order:1}
  #child-2 {order:2}
  #child-3 {order:3}
  #child-4 {order:4}
  #child-5 {order:5}
  #child-6 {order:6}
}
```

```html
<div class="container column">
  <div id="child-1">1</div>
  <div id="child-2">2</div>
  <div id="child-4">4</div>
  <div id="child-3">3</div>
  <div id="child-6">6</div>
  <div id="child-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach makes sense. Thank you sir ;-)